# How to change URL argument from arg-1 to arg_1 before apache processes it? use .htaccess?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a CMS that takes url arguments to return a list of results with this structure:

website.com/argument_1/argument_2.

In order for the site to return the results the args have to have underscores.

However, the code that is generated for the url structure is

website.com/argument-1/argument-2.  I need to keep this url structure, but, when someone clicks the link, I need it passed to PHP via apache with the underscores.

I hope that makes sense. Is this done with .htaccess and rewrite rules? I have never written any thing like that before, so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is much easier done inside PHP... pass everything in, and replace  before parsing the arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely do this in PHP.  Here is a solution that will work, but requires one pass through RewriteRule for each dash in the URL, so I don't recommend it.  But regardless:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)$ $1_$2 [QSA]
```

To clarify what will happen here, if the request is for `http://www.example.com/argument-1/argument-2/argument-3`, the `RewriteRule` will be run multiple times because it can only replace a single dash per pass.  So the URL will be transformed something like this:

```
Pass 1: http://www.example.com/argument-1/argument-2/argument_3 
Pass 2: http://www.example.com/argument-1/argument_2/argument_3 
Pass 3: http://www.example.com/argument_1/argument_2/argument_3
```

As for the `$1` and `$2`, these refer back to the parenthesized components from the regular expression.  The regular expression, `^(.*)-(.*)$`, breaks down like this:

- `^` - Match the beginning of the URI
- `(.*)` - Match (and capture) any number of characters, this will be `$1` in the replacement
- `-` - Match a dash
- `(.*)` - Match (and capture) any number of characters, this will be `$2` in the replacement
- `$` - Match the end of the URI

So the first pass through, `$1` will be `/argument-1/argument-2/argument` and `$2` will be `3`.  The replacement then puts an underscore between the 2 of them and creates a new URI:

```
/argument-1/argument-2/argument_3
```

Then it runs again because the regular expression still matches the new URI (because it has a `-` in it) and `$1` is `/argument-1/argument` and `$2` is `2/argument_3`.  The replacement then puts an underscore between the 2 of them and creates a new URI:

```
/argument-1/argument_2/argument_3
```

Then it runs again because the regular expression still matches the new URI (because it has a `-` in it) and `$1` is `/argument` and `$2` is `1/argument_2/argument_3`.  The replacement then puts an underscore between the 2 of them and creates a new URI:

```
/argument_1/argument_2/argument_3
```

Then Apache continues with this URI since the regular expression no longer matches (because there are no more dashes).

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for a great answer. Are you saying that this is going to provide a lot of overhead? What are the downsides of doing this in the .htaccess file? Looks like a lot of support for a PHP solution. I don't have access to the code that controls this functionality, but, I can write a quick script that is called before the rest of the code and upload it. Should I just change the $_SERVER query string variable and replace it there?  Also, in your answer, $1_$2.. is that for each of the arguments? Can I remove the _$2 for just the first argument or add $2_$3 for a third option?